# Is there a special way to declare methods that need to be known about but not actually used within the class they're declared in?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, nsobject

**This button is declared in my base class:**

```
{
    // Setup done button for tool bar
    UIButton *doneButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 3, 110, 38)];
    [doneButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [doneButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton addTarget:_thisController action:@selector(doneButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return doneButton;
}
```

**Notice this line:**

```
[doneButton addTarget:_thisController action:@selector(doneButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The "doneButtonTapped:" method is only used in each sub class of my base class and never in the base class itself.

**To avoid a warning in the base class I have to at least define the method:**

```
- (void)doneButtonTapped:(id)sender {
}
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to avoid declaring the empty method and not get warnings?

Are blank methods like above a problem?

I know I could addTarget for the selector in each of the sub classes but there are quite a few of them. I just thought leaving everything in the doneButtonTapped method would be easier.

Comment: it's not a problem at all. write in the doc that the sublcass must implement this method and declare it in the header. you can event put the common code to all subclass in this base clase and ask to call [super doneButtonTapped:sender] in the sublcass implementation  like you do with [super viewDidLoad]

Comment: Also maybe have the base method throw some exception, to handle the case that a subclass didnt adhere to the contract and implement it.

Comment: @jordan nice idea if not super implementation is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way ;) :

```
NSString *stringMethod = @"doneButtonTapped:";
[doneButton addTarget:self action:NSSelectorFromString(stringMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In this way you can also change your method at runtime before create the button, just changing the string. And the warning so, are not shown in pre-compile time.

So, enjoy! ;)

Comment: Perfect, wouldn't have known that existed.

Comment: Remember: there is ever a function to bring a string to something else :devil: ;)